# no-index meta-tag Error on a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, list, search

I am getting the following error message in the Crawl Log on our SharePoint 2010 environment (with Search Server 2010 express), when crawling a SharePoint list.

> The content for this address was excluded by the crawler because this
>   item was marked with a no-index meta-tag. To index this item, remove
>   the meta-tag and recrawl.

The list is set to 'Allow items from this list to appear in search results', and the Content Source is set to 'Crawl the Site collection'.

I've no idea where to look, to get rid of the no-index meta-tag.

EDIT: There are no custom crawl rules, no external content types, all services are up and running with the same account, and the account has admin permissions on the server.

Comment: Do you have any specific rules or any external content types?

Comment: Nope, there are no crawl rules and no external content types.